# How to increase the value of a parameter by one in a URL

Tags: reactjs, axios

I use Axios to get users. I get each user one at a time when the button is clicked. I need the ID parameter to increase by 1 when clicked. First it should be "...user/1", and then when clicked "...user/2" and so on. How can I do it?

```js
const Button = () => {
  const handleUser = () => {
    axios.get(".../user/1/").then((res) => {
      ....
    });
  };
  return <button onClick={handleUser}>NEXT</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I,

You need to store the current user id in a state (either directly in your Button component or in its parent component.

ex:

```
const Button = () => {
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(1);

    const handleUser = () => {
        axios.get(`.../user/${userId}/`).then((res) => {
          ....
        }).finally(() => setUserId(userId => userId + 1));
      };

    return <button onClick={handleUser}>NEXT</button>;
};
```

export default Button;

Answer (score 1):

Try this to increment the index of the call.

```
const Button = () => {
  const [index, setIndex]=useState(0)
  const increment = () => {
     setIndex(i => i + 1)
  }
  const handleUser = () => {
    increment()
    axios.get(`.../user/${index}/`).then((res) => {
      ....
    });
  };
  return <button onClick={handleUser}>NEXT</button>;
};

export default Button;
```